# Alexa lists math operations as the top keywords for my website

Tags: keywords, alexa

I viewed my website's Alexa rank for the first time today. I've read that the rank is not very useful, which is fine, but I was confused by one part of the page.

The section called "Top Keywords from Search Engines" has a table with 5 keywords and the percent of search traffic for each. However, the top 2 for my site are odd (the other 3 are understandable):

```
Keyword                Percent of Search Traffic
148*.4*.22/20          51.69% 
148*.4*.22/10          20.75%
```

When I try searching using these, I cannot find my site. In addition, if I search for the name of the site (which, by itself, finds the site as #1) plus one of those keywords, I cannot find the site. And yet these are supposedly over 70% of search traffic.

Does anyone know why my top keywords appear to be math operations?

Comment: Alexa is pure junk. Do not even look at it. Move on. Spend your time on things that matter. The only entities that tell you anything about your traffic is your log files and the search engines. Anyone else cannot possibly have a clue. It is impossible to monitor a sites traffic externally. Impossible! Junk. Pure junk. Do yourself a favor and move on. Cheers!!

Comment: If I could upvote the above comment more I would... Alexa is not reliable.